# Removing formulas but keep the results for ALL sheets in Google Spreedsheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I would like to remove all formulas but keep the results, in ALL sheets.

[It can be done for a selection of cells](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/EaQMwwhA3zc), but I have multiple of sheets and I want a plugin or a way to do it for all sheets.

Comment: Record a macro.

Comment: M.... I don't get why my question is negative voted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below functions to the script editor and save (!!).

```
function onOpen() {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Script')
    .addItem('Remove formulas', 'removeFormulas')
    .addToUi()
}

function removeFormulas() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()
        .forEach(function (sh) {
            var r = sh.getDataRange()
            r.copyTo(r, {
            contentsOnly: true
        })
    })
}
```

Then reopen the spreadsheet and from the menu 'script' click 'Remove formulas'.