# google sheets scritp : create a loop to open each sheet, select all and copy/paste only value without formulas. thank you

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

I have a big google sheet file with +- 420 sheets
So I have to give my colleague without formulas and if it is possible not to do it manually, it will be great for me.

I would like to have a script to open the sheet, select all ( ctrl+a) , copy and paste without formulas ( ctrl+shift+v)
close the sheet and next.

So I need to make a script with a loop to solve this problem and all the operations.

I have already found a script to have all the sheets in a list.

```
  function sheetnames() { 
  var out = new Array()
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
  return out  
}
```

that is ok.

and the screenshot is the list of sheets in my file.
It is in the sheet "for_script" in the file "Entrainements 2021 2022"

[list of sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENXDT.png)

thank you so musch for you help.
Jérôme challe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing formulas but keep the results for ALL sheets in Google Spreedsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50504266/removing-formulas-but-keep-the-results-for-all-sheets-in-google-spreedsheet)

Comment: I cannot understand `I have a big google sheet file with +- 420 sheets` and `list of sheets`. Are the values of the column "A" the sheet names? And, are all sheets put in one Google Spreadsheet which is the active Spreadsheet? By the way, do you want to remove all formulas from all sheets in one Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: Why not giving your colleagues this file as a csv file ? or by the mean of endpoint ? They will upload easily without formulas.

Answer (score 0):

#### Copy DisplayValues

```
function getJSON() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const output = {pA:[]};//you can loop through this to load data later;Every element of this array is a property in the form of a sheet name that contains a 2d array of displayValues
  if(ss.getName() == "Entrainements 2021 2022") {
    const lsh = ss.getSheetByName("for_script");
    const list = lsh.getRange(1,1,lsh.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().flat();
    ss.getSheets().filter(s => ~list.indexOf(s.getName())).forEach(sh => {
      if(!output.hasOwnProperty(sh.getName())) {
        output[sh.getName()]=sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
        output.pA.push(sh.getName());
      } 
    })
  }
  return JSON.stringify(output);//return as JSON
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create csv files in one folder and share this folder

```
function makeCSVFiles() {
  const folderID = 'YOUR FOLDER ID'
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID); 
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().forEach(sh => {
    var csv = "";
    sh.getDataRange().getValues().forEach(d => {
      csv += d.join(",") + "\n";
    })
    var fileId = DriveApp.createFile(sh.getName() + ".csv", csv).getId()
    DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).moveTo(folder)
  })
}
```